# Call custom javascript code on list new form save button

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-list

I have to write a java script code which copies the look up column value into a single line of text.I should call this script on list New form OOB Save button click.
How should I call this custom code on list New form OOB Save button click.

Please help on this.

Comment: Have you tried using `PreSaveFunction()`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using modern UI, you should either customize a form with [PowerApps](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/) or use another designer of forms, e.g. [Plumsail Forms](https://plumsail.com/forms/sharepoint-forms/). There're no other ways to run custom code in a SharePoint form.